# cryptic TypeScript error message when not returning the state from a reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript

here is the demo of the a simple counter I created for practising TS with React.

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-murdock-gtfv8?file=/src/App.tsx

Here I have a reducer defined like this

```
function reducer(state: State, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionType.INCREMENT: {
      return { count: state.count + action.payload };
    }
    case actionType.DECREMENT: {
      return { count: state.count + action.payload };
    }
    default:
      neverReached(action);
  }
  return state;
}
```

Here `neverReached` is a util function I use to catch unhandled cases.

```
const neverReached = (never: never) => {};
```

However if I omit the return i.e. `return state;`. TS would raise an error on this line
`const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialCount, init);`, specifically

> var initialCount: number No overload matches this call.   The last
> overload gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

I cannot seem to understand the error. Why does it occur after I omit the return in the reducer?

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve your issue? if so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to further help you with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***What* Happens?**

When you omit the `return` in your code, Typescript tries to find a `React.useReducer` overload to be called, but it can't find one. As the error says, the error is emitted by the *last* overload.

Now, what's that last overload? the emitted error helpfully has that information:

> index.d.ts(1002, 14): The last overload is declared here.

Diving into the source code, we can see that this overload is:

```
function useReducer<R extends Reducer<any, any>>(
    reducer: R,
    initialState: ReducerState<R>,
    initializer?: undefined
): [ReducerState<R>, Dispatch<ReducerAction<R>>];
```

Now, instead of thinking too hard what are the inferred types of this overload, let's just copy-paste it into your code, and call it directly:

```
function useReducer<R extends React.Reducer<any, any>>(
  reducer: R,
  initialState: React.ReducerState<R>,
  initializer?: undefined
): [React.ReducerState<R>, React.Dispatch<React.ReducerAction<R>>];

export default function App({ initialCount = 1 }: Props) {
  useReducer(reducer, initialCount, init); // <-- called directly
}
```

We can now hover `useReducer` direct call and see the inferred types:

```
function useReducer<(state: State, action: Action) => {
    count: number;
} | undefined>(reducer: (state: State, action: Action) => {
    count: number;
} | undefined, initialState: never, initializer?: undefined):  [...]
```

As you can see, `initialState` inferred type is `never`, while the passed-in `initialCount` type is `number`, thus you get that error message.

***Why* It Happens?**

When Typescript cannot resolve a type, it concludes it's a `never` type. [As per the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html):

> Variables also acquire the type `never` when narrowed by any type guards that can never be true.

In your code, we have a situation that is essentially like defining:

```
type resolvedAsNever = string & number
```

This is because the last overload has `initialState: ReducerState<R>`, while the passed-in `initialCount` type is `number`. Typescript can't make a valid type out of `ReducerState<R> & number`.